# how to set duration businessHours

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm trying to make my calendar using the fullcalendar api. But I don't find how to set the duration for the settings businessHours. I would like to get a different view businessHours on the different week or another month.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by set the duration for the buisnessHours? You want a custom view to only have buisnessHours? Show your code of what you are trying to accomplish.